# MySql Trigger base on form field

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this trigger on my mysql database and work, but now i need to add a condition to the trigger if a value in the form  field Company=MyCompany if not the trigger do not run

my actual code is:

```sql
INSERT INTO documents (employeeId, DocumentName, ExpirationTime,type)
SELECT NEW.Id, Docname, ExpirationTime, type FROM docs
```

Any idea on this. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add an If condition in your code -

```
IF Company = MyCompany THEN
     INSERT INTO documents (employeeId, DocumentName, ExpirationTime,type)
         SELECT NEW.Id, Docname, ExpirationTime, type FROM docs
END IF;
```

Comment: Thanks, i will try this